# SMO to script just the database and it settings (not the objects in it)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I have put together a nice PowerShell script to script out the objects (tables, functions, sprocs etc) from a database, limiting it to the ones in a list.

But I am stuck trying to find a way to script the database itself.  Each time I do that, it seems to try to script out the whole database (it is way to large for that to go well).

Assuming I have a `$db` variable that is a reference to my database, **how can I use SMO to script out that database, creating it with the same Properties and DatabaseScopedConfigurations**, but none of the actual objects in it?

---

Update:

For reference here is my current script.  It takes a server and database name and will script out all the objects found in a file called DbObjectsList.txt (assuming they are in the database).  But this does not actually make the database.  The database I am running this on is a legacy one, and it has a bunch of odd options set.  I would like to preserve those.

```
$serverName = "MyServerName" 
$databaseName = "MyDbName"

$date_ = (date -f yyyyMMdd)
$path = ".\"+"$date_"

 # Load the Sql Server Management Objects (SMO) and output to null so we don't show the dll details.
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') > $null 
# Setup the scripting options
$scriptOptions = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions')
$scriptOptions.ExtendedProperties = $true
$scriptOptions.AnsiPadding = $true
$scriptOptions.ClusteredIndexes = $true
# Dri = Declarative Referential Integrity
$scriptOptions.DriAll  = $true
$scriptOptions.Triggers  = $true
$scriptOptions.NoCollation  = $false
$scriptOptions.SchemaQualify  = $true
$scriptOptions.ScriptSchema  = $true
$scriptOptions.EnforceScriptingOptions = $true
$scriptOptions.SchemaQualifyForeignKeysReferences = $true
$scriptOptions.NonClusteredIndexes  = $true
$scriptOptions.Statistics  = $true
$scriptOptions.Permissions  = $true
$scriptOptions.OptimizerData = $true

# get a reference to the database we are going to be scripting from
$serverInstance = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $serverName
$db=$serverInstance.Databases | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $databaseName}

$dbname = "$db".replace("[","").replace("]","")
$dbpath = "$path"+ "\"+"$dbname" + "\"
if ( !(Test-Path $dbpath))
{
    $null=new-item -type directory -name "$dbname"-path "$path"
}

# Load the list of db objects we want to script.
$listPath = ".\DbObjectList.txt"
if ((Test-Path $listPath))
{
    $dbListItems = Get-Content -Path $listPath
}
else 
{
    throw "Could not find DbObjectst.txt file (it should have a list of what to script)."
}

# Setup the output file, removing any existing one
$outFile = "$dbpath" + "FullScript.sql"
if ((Test-Path $outFile)){Remove-Item $outFile }

$typeDelimiter = "=========="
foreach ($dbListItem in $dbListItems)
{
    # Let the caller know which one we are working on.
    echo $dbListItem
    if ($dbListItem.StartsWith($typeDelimiter))
    {
        # Pull the type out of the header
        $startIndex = $typeDelimiter.Length;
        $stopIndex = $dbListItem.LastIndexOf($typeDelimiter)
        $type = $dbListItem.Substring($startIndex, $stopIndex - $startIndex).Trim()
        continue;
    }

    if ($type -eq $null)
    {
        throw "Types not included DbObjectsList.txt.  Add types before groups of objects, surrounded by " + $typeDelimiter      
    }   


    foreach ($dbObjectToScript in $db.$type)
    {
        $objName = "$dbObjectToScript".replace("[","").replace("]","")
        $compareDbListItem = "$dbListItem".replace("[","").replace("]","")
        if ($compareDbListItem -eq $objName)
        {
            "-- " + $dbListItem | out-File -Append $outFile 
            $dbObjectToScript.Script($scriptOptions)+"GO" | out-File -Append $outFile 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "script out" - you're wanting the script/function to return the T-SQL to re-create the database objects as a string/file? Maybe add your existing code + expected output and current issues your facing

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - I added my script and more details.

Comment: `$scriptOptions.ScriptData = $false`